# JavaFX: How to manage focusedProperty between different nodes?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a **listener** attached to my studentIDText field that fetches the Student record from the database. I do however show an Error message if I leave the field empty. However, when I land up clicking on the Exit button, I still land up getting the Error message which won't go away until I fetch the record again or re-enter something in StudentIdText field.

When clicking on the Exit button, I have tried to set the focus on a different field (In this case a hidden one). I have also tried it on another field like First Name but the alert will not go away.

```
// StudentController.java
public class StudentController {
@FXML private TextField studentIdText;
@FXML private TextField lastNameText;
@FXML private TextField firstNameText;

//Exit the program
@FXML
public void handleExit(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    hiddenText.requestFocus();
    System.exit(0);
}

@FXML
public static void showErrorMessage(String infoMessage, String titleBar, String headerMessage)
{
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle(titleBar);
    alert.setHeaderText(headerMessage);
    alert.setContentText(infoMessage);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

@FXML
private void initialize () {
// Listener to studentIdText field
    studentIdText.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, wasFocused, focused) -> {
        if (!focused && !studentIdText.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
          searchStudent();
        }
        else {
            showErrorMessage("Enter valid Student ID#", "Student DB", "");
            studentIdText.requestFocus();
        }
    });

@FXML
private void searchStudent() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
  if (!studentIdText.getText().isEmpty()) {
    //Get Student information
    Student stu = StudentDAO.searchStudent(studentIdText.getText());
    populateAndShowStudent(stu);
  }
}
```

The Error message "Enter valid Student ID#" shows up all the time until I enter any text in the StudentIdText field. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search for a student if the user didn't enter anything:

```java
studentIdText.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, wasFocused, focused) -> {
    if (!focused && !studentIdText.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        searchStudent();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @M. S. That does make sense but the issue arises if the User entered a Student ID and retrieved a record and then went back to the Student ID field and removed it. Besides, if User does not enter anything in the Student ID field and presses the tab, I want to show the error message "Enter valid Student ID#"

Comment: You can add else to this if. If the text field is empty, show an error alert, else if there is a value try fetching it from your data source.

Comment: I landed up cleaning up my code a bit (Removed the try and catch statements for now). I landed up having two issues: (1) IllegalStateException: showAndWait is not allowed during animation or layout processing and (2) When I clear the screen or the first time I run my form, the Else fires right away (Which means that the Alert would keep coming up if I just change my Alert to say alert.show() instead of alert.showAndWait()